# R: Create binary data from a data frame

Tags: r, binary-data

i need some advise for the following problem:

I have a dataframe with two columns, one containing the date, the other the frequency of a an event. 
Now i want to add a third column to this dataframe, wich should contain some binary data: 1 for days with a frequency of 100 and higher, 0 for the lower ones.

Has anyone an idea how to do this in a smart way (i'm affraid of writing it by hand;-)? Thanks for your answer in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df$freq.gt.100 = as.integer(df$freq >= 100)`

The bit inside brackets evaluates to `TRUE` or `FALSE` which can be converted to 1 or 0 via `as.integer`.

There's nothing to be "afraid" of: you can test the right-hand side of the expression on its own to check it works and only when you are happy with this do you add it as a new column to the original data.

EDIT: didn't see the above answer as I was creating this one and had a call to take!

Answer (score 2):

```
data$newcol = as.integer(data$freq >= 100)
```

alternatively

```
data$newcol = ifelse(data$freq >= 100, 1, 0)
```

alternatively

```
data$newcal = 0
data$newcol[data$freq >= 100] = 1
```

Comment: Or more simply `data$newcol <- ( data$freq >= 100 ) * 1L`

Comment: I would rather prefer `data$newcol = as.integer(data$freq >= 100)`

Comment: yes, that too. Point being, it's not necessary to use two calls and you certainly should not use `ifelse` here when faster vectorised methods exist.